# How to access google sheets with python 2023?

Tags: python, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to follow the [Python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python), but it seems to be outdated or I'm not understanding something.

I'm using the exact code there, but here is the important

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']

# The ID and range of a sample spreadsheet.
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms'
SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME = 'Class Data!A2:E'


def main():
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)

return
```

Which gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/oauth2/credentials.py", line 450, in from_authorized_user_file
    return cls.from_authorized_user_info(data, scopes)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/oauth2/credentials.py", line 399, in from_authorized_user_info
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Authorized user info was not in the expected format, missing fields client_id, refresh_token, client_secret.
```

Obviously the `token.json` is wrong, but I got it exactly how they describe in the tutorial. To download again, I can got to [Google cloud Credentials](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials), and under **OAuth 2.0 Client IDs** I can download the OAuth.

Indeed if I inspect the `json` file, it does not contain `client_id,` `refresh_token` or `client_secret`. So what am I missing? Am I downloading the wrong credentials, is the python code outdated with the google API? What's going on?

To be clear: There are many questions that are similar to this one, but they seem to follow the tutorial and seem to be getting stuck somewhere else.

Comment: I think that when I saw the script of Quickstart for Sheets API, the file of `token.json` is created when the browser authorizes the scopes. At that time, the file including the client ID, client secret, and so on is used. And, the file including the client ID, client secret, and so on is used at `flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)` in the script of Quickstart for Python. In your showing script, I'm worried that you might not correctly use the script of Quickstart for Python. If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize.